# how to flatten inner array objects without getting cartesian product of the properties

Tags: json, command-line, jq

[You can see a demo of the problem in the following jq play: https://jqplay.org/s/Lx7eM2akzp]

Having the following array

```
{
  "t": "0",
  "d": "12090",
  "w": "1",
  "s": [
    {
      "ac": "252",
      "$t": "pastas"
    },
    {
      "t": "1280",
      "ac": "226",
      "$t": "299"
    },
    {
      "t": "2780",
      "ac": "252",
      "$t": "187"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I flatten the inner array such that I can run queries similar to

```sh
jq '{ "absolute": .t, "word": .s[]."$t", "relative": .s[].t, }'
```

so that I get results such as:

```
{
  "absolute": "0",
  "word": "pastas",
  "relative": null
}
{
  "absolute": "0",
  "word": "299",
  "relative": "1280"
}
{
  "absolute": "0",
  "word": "187",
  "relative": "2780"
}
```

instead of all the combinations between the inner properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the iterator is `.s[]` and we want just one of them:

```
.s[] as $s
| { "absolute": .t, "word": $s."$t", "relative": $s.t }
```

Or, if you want to be a little DRYer:

```
{"absolute": .t} + (.s[] | {"word": ."$t", "relative": .t})
```